# Modifying SharePoint System Files

Tags: sharepoint

What is the general feeling amongst developers regarding the changing of files in the 12 hive. 
For example if you were asked to remove the sign is a different user menu item, you would need to modify the relevent user control on the filesystem. Now if you just go and modify it via notepad or copy over and then if you go and bring a new server into the farm you will need to remember to do the same on the new server. 
Obvouisly you could deploy the changed file as a solution and have that done automatically, but I'm just wondering if people are hesitant to make changes to the default installed files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a bit of SharePoint development, and I must tell you that messing with the 12-hive is a ticket to a world of pain if you ever want to move the app.

I'd rather hack up some javascript to hide it, at least that can be bound to the master page, which is much more portable.
And remember, you never know when the next service pack comes around and nukes your changes :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lars.  Sometimes you will not be able to avoid it, depending on your needs.  But, in general the best policy is to avoid modification if at all possible.

I know that some of the other menu items in the current user menu (change login, my settings, etc) can be changed by removing permissions from the user.  Under Users and Groups there is an option for permissions.  I can't remember the exact setting (develop at work, not at home), but there are reasonable descriptions next to each of the 30+ permissions.  Remove it and you start hiding menu options.  No modifications to the 12-hive needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple rule: if you want to keep official support from Microsoft, don't change any of the files in the 12 hive that are installed by SharePoint.

I've never encountered a situation where the only solution was to change such a file. For example if you want to change an out-of-the-box user control of SharePoint, you can do so by making use of the DelegateControl, and overriding it in a feature.

More info:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx
- http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/36628

I know it's tempting to quickly change a file, and I have to admit sometimes I just do that on a DEV box, but don't go there on a production server!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is much use pitching in, as everyone else pretty much has it covered, but I would also say don't do it. As tempting as it is, its just impossible to know the full impact of that little change you have made.

From a support perspective you will make it difficult for Microsoft support (patches/hotfixes).
From a maintenance perspective you are also opening yourself up to long term costs.

Go the javascript route.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about it is to use a Sharepoint Solution (WSP) file.

To change the user control, create a new Sharepoint feature with the new functionality.

Include this feature in your solution.

Deploy the solution either using the stsadm command line, or through Central Site Admin.

This will then get automatically deployed to all the servers in your farm, and it avoids you overwriting anything default sharepoint files.

For more info, check out Sharepoint Nuts and Bolts blog on http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/ which give an introduction to WSP and Sharepoint Features.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this many times and I will speak from experience: Never ever touch the onet.xml files within the 12 hive under any circumstance. Any error that you make in there, and to make the CAML even more complex the file is largely whitespace sensitive, will have an impact on every part of SharePoint.

You should also consider that aside from the substantial risk to the installation, you may well be building in dependencies upon your changes that are then over-written in a future patch or service pack.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you can accomplish everything you want to using features and solution packages without modifying the files.  However, there are a few (rather annoying) rare cases where your only option would be to modify a file on the system.  I have used it for two particular cases so far.  One was to add the PDF iFilter to the docicon.xml file, and the other was to add a theme to the themes.xml file.  In both cases, it seemed to be the only way to achieve the goal.  Still, we used a solution package to write those files out to all the servers in the farm.